# How can I access a express session in socket.io events?

Tags: node.js, session, express, websocket, socket.io

I'm currently playing around with express and socket.io and built an app that only accepts socket.io connections from users that have logged in. I put up a simple example. See the **io.sockets.on('connection')** part especially:

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express();
var http = require('http').createServer(app);

var io = require('socket.io').listen(http);

var sessionStore = new express.session.MemoryStore();

io.set('authorization', function (handshake, accept)
{
    // I got this from a gist.
    // Don't know the link anymore, though.
    var cookies = require('express/node_modules/cookie').parse(handshake.headers.cookie);
    var parsed = require('express/node_modules/connect/lib/utils').parseSignedCookies(cookies, 'SESSION_SECRET');

    sessionStore.get(parsed.sid, function (error, session)
    {
        if (error != null)
        {
            accept(error, false);
            return;
        }

        if (session != null && session.user != null)
        {
            accept(null, true);
        }
        else
        {
            accept('Not a logged in user.', false);
        }
    });
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket)
{
    // client with an user object in his session (= logged in)
    // connected. But how can I access this session in here?
});

app.use(express.cookieParser('COOKIE_SECRET'));

app.use(express.session({
    secret: 'SESSION_SECRET',
    key: 'sid',
    store: sessionStore
}));

app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.use(express.json());

app.get('/', function (request, response)
{
    response.sendfile('static/index.html');
});

app.post('/', function (request, response)
{
    request.session.user = null;

    var post = request.body;

    if (post.username === 'admin' && post.password === 'admin')
    {
        request.session.user = post;
    }

    response.redirect('/');
});

http.listen(80);
```

Everything works to this point. Only users which have a user in their session (= they're logged in) can connect via socket.io. However, I'm currently stuck at the point when a client actually does so because I can't get a session on that point.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood this question then you want express session later at some point with your `socket` object. You can do it like this:

```
if (session != null && session.user != null){
   accept(null, true);
   handshake.session = session;
}
```

And you can access this by doing this:

```
socket.handshake.session
```

Hope this will work

Answer (score 0):

You can use [passport.socketio](https://www.npmjs.org/package/passport.socketio).